# Execute elements one after another after page load

Tags: javascript, css

I'm working with animate.css - https://daneden.me/animate/ and I was wondering if it was possible to have multiple elements use the CSS animations and execute one after another on page load.

These are the three different elements I want to use:

```
<img src="flowers.png" data-test="bounceInDown" class="animated bounceInDown" />
<img src="dog.png" data-test="bounceInDown" class="animated bounceInDown" />
<img src="speechbubble.png" data-test="bounceInDown" class="animated bounceInDown" />
```

I just need help executing the animations one after another on page-load.

Thank You.

Comment: Could you use jQuery to loop through and add the classes dynamically?

Comment: I'm not really good with JS, which is why I was asking for help.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to stick with just CSS, you can use the `animation-delay` sub-property to time them out... add another class to your `img` tags then add the following CSS *before* the original CSS for the animation:

```
img.class1{
    animation-delay: 3s;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 3s;
}
img.class2{
    animation-delay: 6s;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 6s;
}
img.class3{
    animation-delay: 9s;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 9s;
}
```

You'll have to do a little bit of back and forth testing to get the timing down right, but it shouldn't be too complicated. Here is a fiddle of `animation-delay` in action: http://jsfiddle.net/Ny4XH/